# jquery get width dynamically as browser width resizes

Tags: jquery, width

I am not very experienced with jQuery so would appreciate help with the following, currently I can get the width of a specified div in pixels which is fine, but I would like to develop this further and be able to list a number of divs to get the width of in the attached code.

You'll see i have #divA, well i would like to also get #divB & #divC in the same statement for example. eg (i tried this but it isnt correct) >

```
var txt="";
txt+="Width of div: " + $("#divA, #divB, #divC").width() + "</br>";
txt+="Height of div: " + $("#divA, #divB, #divC").height();
$("#divA, #divB, #divC").html(txt);
```

Also can the outputted div widths update on the fly as the viewport/browser changes width -  is this possible? Would save page refreshing which would be handy.

Hope that makes sense.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){

var txt="";
txt+="Width of div: " + $("#divA").width() + "</br>";
txt+="Height of div: " + $("#divA").height();
$("#divA").html(txt);


});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What are you using the widths and heights for? Changing the size of elements on window resize can be done without Jquery/Javascript. It's called media queries and is really a joy to work with (works only in modern browsers).

Comment: I want to visually see in the browser what the width of the div is in pixels - the divs are set up in percentages so they adjust to the viewport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Without your mark up I have created my own with 3 divs (like yours). When the window resized their height and width are logged to the console. Their width is set as %. I hope this helps.

Let me know if this is what you want. I am not 100% sure what you are asking for.

**Demo:**

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jRrZz/)

**Javascript:**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".divResized").each(function(i,item){
        item = $(item);
        console.log(item.width(),item.height())
    });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<div id="divA" class="divResized">
    test
</div>
<div id="divB" class="divResized">
    test1
</div>
<div id="divC" class="divResized">
    test2
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#divA{
    width:33%;
}

#divB{
    width:17%;
}

divC{
    width:50%;
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you want it written to another div, here's a small example of that: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jRrZz/1/)

Comment: Xeano, thats exactly what i was after thanks, good to see another/better way of doing this

Comment: Hi Xeano, im just trying to adjust this so it displays the result in each div rather than an external one as in your 2nd example - couldnt get the first working for some reason

Comment: Thats it : ) - I thought that was what your first jsfiddle was supposed to do but some of the js is a bit different. Thanks